# malicious website blocked - on a legit program?

Tags: antimalware

I'm fairly okay with PCs but when it comes to networking i'm quite lost with the details. 
My brother started up Mount and blade war band napleonic wars - an official game and played multi player and joined a server. All of a sudden malwarebytes starts blocking outbound connections to 176.53.17.226, on ports 49287, 63932, 65135, 57512, and 60600.

Is my pc in danger? Or is it a false positive? Please help. It showed mountblade warband_/mb_warband.exe being blocked

Answer (score 1):

After a quick google search I found [THIS](http://www.herdprotect.com/mb_warband.exe-efdc05a53e3351703c108449c93c135afc32ce76.aspx) and according to them it's fine. mb_warband.exe is known to be published by a legitimate company (Taleworlds Entertainment) so everything should be fine. If this was happening to me I'd treat it as a false positive.

Comment: I bought the game from Steam which is a legit company. So am I completely safe playing the game?

Comment: As I posted in my answer, it appears to be safe and if it was happening on my machine I would treat it as a false positive. I can't guarantee anything, but again if it was my machine I would allow it.

Comment: What would be indicators if it was malicious? Also, if I auninstall malwarebytes, I wont have to worry playing multi player again? None of this happened on singleplayer, only as soon as my brother went on a multi player game.

Comment: Single player doesn't need to make lots of connections for data from other players etc.

Comment: As I understand it, MWB sees that data which appears unique (especially with an identifying pattern) is being sent externally, and it doesn't have the site in a whitelist of known-good IPs. Everything about your actions in multiplayer is data which appears unique (your moves) with an identifying pattern (your game handle/session ID etc so the game knows who's making those moves). Given that there are millions of games out there with online multiplayer, MWB may not know about every single IP they use... especially if you connect directly to the other player.